# Salesforce lightning: how to add a custom global value provider

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, aura, global-variables

This question has been raised [before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115111/how-to-use-a-set-or-how-to-add-a-custom-global-value-provider) but I haven't seen a satisfactory answer to it.

Basically I want to make global variable (which is a chart object reference) available to all components (for event handlers etc to have access to the object).

If I switch locker services off I can simply graft the object reference into the aura $A global

```
$A.netChart = new NetChart({
            container: ctx,
           area: { height: 350 }, 
 ...
```

But going forward this wont be a viable option with locker services being mandated.

The other suggestion is to use a custom global value provider:

```
myChart = new chart(); 
$A.set('myChartObject', myChart);
```

But lightning doesn't currently support custom global value providers and the above causes an exception to be thrown.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to make the global chart variable available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using static resources and defining the global variables like below

**Approach 1 involves using a static resource file to store all the global values**

Here is how a code in your static resource look like

```
(function(w){
  "use strict"; //Optional because LC on LockerService active runs in strict mode

 var globalConstants = {
    "variable1":"abc",
    "variable2":"zyz"
  };

  w.globalvalues = globalConstants;

})(window);
```

And then in lightning component you will use like below

```
 ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.TestScript}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />

 afterScriptsLoaded : function(cmp){
   globalvalues.variable1; 
   globalvalues.variable2; 
 }
```

**Approach 2: An application event fired on init call and all the components handle it** .